# Unix Sed Command

Tags: sed

Hi Could someone help to explain the meaning of the following syntax? I know it is regex but I could not understand s#

`sed -r "s#\{\"result\":\{\"status\":\"S\"\}\}##g" $data_get > $data`

Comment: Don't let the `s#` confuse you.  It's the same as `s/`.  They're just using a different delimiter than normal, i.e. `#` rather than `/`.

Comment: In addition to the explanation about `#` from Steve and in the duplicates, if you're working with JSON data, it may be more reliable edited with `jq` than with `sed`. You may want to ask a separate question about that.  Also, most of the backslashes are not needed in that expression.

Comment: Indeed.  I believe the line could be reduced to simply `sed 's/{"result":{"status":"S"}}//g' $data_get > $data` and achieve the same behaviour.